# Why is the "Review Suggested Edits" dialog box missing its title?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

On the Close Votes queue, there is `Why should this question be closed?` indicating what the dialog's purpose is.

[image]

On the Suggested Edits, there is nothing.

[image]

However, looking at the source, it seems they initially had the title, but the html is messed.

`<h2&gt;why are="" you="" rejecting="" this="" edit?<="" h2="">`

[image]

### Edit:

The fix looks great! However...

The new dialog has some padding that looks a bit weird:

[image]

The other popups do not have the spacing at the top.

On closer inspection of the source, I see `popup-tab-content`.

[image]

It seems to be causing the spacing, as when I un-nested the form from the div, the result was:

[image]

Lastly, the dialog for every other review queue allows movement from the title. (Hover your mouse over, and you can move the dialog)

This is with the code:

```
<h2 class="popup-title-container handle" style="cursor: move;">
    <span class="popup-breadcrumbs"></span><span class="popup-title">Why are you rejecting this edit?</span>
</h2>
```

Sorry if I'm being picky :)

Comment: Localization, it's always localization. :/

Comment: +1 because the messed up HTML made me laugh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dumb error, literally putting `>` into a string.  Even without localization involvement it would have broken, as Razor will encode any string.

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect the change. sorry if I'm asking too much

Comment: @DaveChen removal of extra padding and ability to be moved will be in the next build - thanks for pointing it out.