# Editing help for lists shows $dash$ instead of minus sign

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing-help

The current [editing help page for simple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists) shows the following:

> $dash$ Use a minus sign for a bullet
>
> $dash$ This list gets wrapped in `<p>` tags

The same thing also occurs in Advanced Lists: Nesting

Comment: Blame [Razor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193281/152859)! ;)

Comment: Oh my goodness, another one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this went out in the latest deploy.